# Google Cloud Composer using Terraform

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-composer

I am new to Terraform, is there any straight forward way to manage and create Google Cloud Composer environment using Terraform?

I checked the supported list of components for GCP seems like Google Cloud Composer is not there as of now. As a work around I am thinking of creating a shell script including required gcloud composer cli commands and run it using Terraform, is it a right approach? Please suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 6):

Google Cloud Composer is now supported in Terraform: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/composer_environment

It can be used as below

```
resource "google_composer_environment" "test" {
  name   = "my-composer-env"
  region = "us-central1"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is an option. You can use a [`null_resource`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/null_resource.html) and [`local-exec`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html) to run commands:

```
resource "null_resource" "composer" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    inline = [
      "gcloud beta composer <etc..>"
    ]
  }
}
```

Just keep in mind when using `local-exec`:

> Note that even though the resource will be fully created when the
>   provisioner is run, there is no guarantee that it will be in an
>   operable state

It looks like [Google Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2018/05/cloud-composer-is-now-in-beta-build-and-run-practical-workflows-with-minimal-effort) is really new and still in beta. Hopefully Terraform will support it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had to use a slightly different syntax with the provisioner that included a command parameter.

```
resource "null_resource" "composer" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "gcloud composer environments create <name> --project <project> --location us-central1 --zone us-central1-a --machine-type n1-standard-8"
  }
}
```

While this works, it is disconnected from the actual resource state in GCP.   It'll rely on the state file to say whether it exists, and I found I had to taint it to get the command to run again.